# Topic stability in LDA models

Tags: model, lda, stability

My major is bioinformatics and I want to use LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) to explain histone code of a lot of genes.

I used the LDA model in my project, when I re-run my topic models with a different random seed, the topic terms seem to change dramatically.

I certainly do not want to my results to be an artifact of a random seed. Is there anything I can do to figure it out?

Comment: Can you give more details about the language and libraries you're using?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I have a similar problem. My solution has been to run the model many times and average the results.